plantuml-mit-1.2024.6.jar Warning: no image in restart_mgmt.plantuml No diagram found
This is a minimal example for a sequence diagram:
@startuml example

bob->anne: hello

The Visual Studio Code plugin PlantUML shows no error, but the java app cannot create an image:
java -jar "plantuml-mit-1.2024.6.jar" -tpng exmaple.plantuml
Warning: no image in exmaple.plantuml
No diagram found


The @enduml tag was missing and the warning not too precise.
The following works with the vscode extension as well as the command line java app:
@startuml example

bob->anne: hello

@enduml

